# laravel modal show Client informations

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm fetching clients' information:

```
<table class="mytable" id="table">
<tr><th>Nom</th><th>Prenom</th><th>CIN</th><th>Email</th><th 
width="20%">Action</th></tr>
{{ csrf_field() }}
@foreach($clients as $client)
<tr class="client{{$client->cin}}">
<td>{{ $client->nom }}</td><td>{{ $client->prenom }}</td><td>{{ $client- 
>cin }}</td><td>{{ $client->email }}</td>
<td>
<span><a type="button" class="show-modal" href="#"  data-nom="{{$client- 
>nom}}" data-prenom="{{$client->prenom}}"  data-tel="{{$client->tel}}" 
data-cin="{{$client->cin}}" data-email="{{$client->email}}"><img 
src="img/ac3.png"></a></span>
</td></tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

When I click on the show button I would like to display clients' information.
For the moment everything is ok with this code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
$('#show').modal('show');
$('#nom').text($(this).data('nom'));
$('#prenom').text($(this).data('prenom'));
$('#tel').text($(this).data('tel'));
$('#cin').text($(this).data('cin'));
$('#email').text($(this).data('email'));
});
```

I show it in this modal:

```
<div class="table-responsive"> 
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<tr>
<th >NOM</th>
<td id="nom"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th >PRENOM</th>
<td id="prenom"></td>
</tr>
<th >TELEPHONE</th>
<td id="tel"></td>
</tr>
<th >CIN</th>
<td id="cin"></td>
</tr>
<th >Email</th>
<td id="email"></td>
</tr>
</table>
<h4 style="color:#005b7f">Liste des voitures occupé par ce client</h4>
<table class="mytable">

<tr><th>Date de prise</th><th>Date de fin</th><th>Matricule</th><th>details 
de contrat</th></tr>
@foreach ($client->locations as $location)
<tr><td>{{$location->date_prise}}</td><td>{{$location->date_fin}}</td><td> 
{{$location->voiture_matricule}}</td><td><a href="#">Voir plus</a></td></tr>
@endforeach 
</table>
```

the problem is here:
I have a relation between the table client and the table location.
and the table voiture also has a relation with the table location.
this is the Client Modal:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class client extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'cin';

public $incrementing = false;
public function locations()
{
return $this->hasMany(Location::class);
}
}
```

When I click the button show I would like, despite of showing the clients' information, also show the cars occupied by this client.
Then I need to pass my client's cin to my controller or my view. Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, add following entry in your  section of into header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

You can call ajax function on click event

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
    //Along with your modal action you can use following code
     $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    var id = $(this).data('nom');
    $.post('client/'+id, function(response){ 
        if(response.success)
        {
            var html = '<tr><th>Date de prise</th><th>Date de fin</th><th>Matricule</th>
                <th>details de contrat</th></tr>' ;
            $.each(response.car_data, function(i, car_data){
                html = html + "<td>" + car_data.date_prise +"</td>" + "<td>" + car_data.date_fin +"</td>"
                +"<td>" + car_data.voiture_matricule +"</td>";
            }).appendTo("#mytable");
        }
    },'json');
});
```

Here, url should match the url of your route declaration for the clients, for example,if you have declared a route like this:

```
Route::post('client/{id}', 'Controller@getclient');
```

You can get Client information using following function :

```
public function getClientData($id){
    $car_data = array();
    //with client id you can write logic and send output in car_data variable  through json
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'car_data' => $car_data]);
}
```

You can remove foreach loop below h4 tag in modal html and use following code

```
<table class="mytable" id="mytable">
</table>
```

Hope this will give you idea.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response it very helpful.
i think the logic you made is right . i did the same , but i still got nothing in my view

here's my ajax :

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

//show function 
 $(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
//Along with your modal action you can use following code

var cin = $(this).data('cin');
$.post('client/'+cin, function(response){ 
    if(response.success)
    {
        var html = '<tr><th>Date de prise</th><th>Date de fin</th><th>Matricule</th><th>details de contrat</th></tr>' ;
        $.each(response.car_data, function(i, car_data){
            html = html + "<td>" + car_data.date_prise +"</td>" + "<td>" + car_data.date_fin +"</td>"
            +"<td>" + car_data.voiture_matricule +"</td>";
        }).appendTo("#mytable");
    }

},'json');

});
```

here's my Controller , i tested the output of my Controller and it is working, so i think the problem is in the ajax function :

```
public function getclientData($cin){
$car_dat = array();
//with client id you can write logic and send output in car_data variable  through json

$car_dat= Client::find(cin);
$car_data=array();
$car_data=$car_dat->locations;

return response()->json(['success' => true, 'car_data' => $car_data]);
}
```

my route:

```
Route::post('client/{cin}', 'ClientsController@getclientData');
```

i think the problem may be in the ajax function ,because i didn't get even the

```
var html = '<tr><th>Date de prise</th><th>Date de fin</th><th>Matricule</th> 
<th>details de contrat</th></tr>' ;
```

in my view.

i also added the meta token in the header.
thank you for any answear.

Comment: yes @ShaanSetia the problem is solved.thank you for your help